# How can I create a delete button for each entity in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a simple post system with the Symfony 2 framework. I want the page to display a list of `DiscussionPost` entities that are fetched from the database. For each post, I want to render a small delete button that will remove the respective post and persist the deletion to the database if the `User` field matches the currently logged in user.

Here is the entity file for `DiscussionPost`.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="discussion_post")
*/
class DiscussionPost
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    */
    protected $user;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=140, nullable=false)
    */
    protected $text;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $postTime;

// getters and setters...
```

I have already looked at the form collection article in the Symfony Cookbook:

[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

However, this example is for multiple Tasks, each with a list of Tags that can be modified. My case is more similar to a list of Tasks that needs to be modified.

I also plan to have a form below the list of posts that is used to add a new post and persist it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delete form for each record in your template with just the button and id in a hidden field and use jQuery to remove the item from the page and to AJAX so you don't have to reload the page every time.